# Ambiguous use of subscript when attempting to use physical simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, ios-simulator, ambiguous

I am attempting to run my application on a physical device (iPhone 6+) and I keep getting this error message. **Ambiguous use of subscript**. When running the application on the simulator everything runs fine, I am wondering if it is an issue that corresponds to using a physical device.

```
//Making array to sort through the index of the specific field
        if let array = allUsers["user_info"] {
            for index in 0...array.count-1 {
                let aObject = array[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
                let Emails = aObject["email"] as! String
                let Passwords = aObject["password"] as! String
                user_info[Emails] = Passwords as AnyObject?
            }
        }
```

I am getting the error on the following line: **let aObject = array[index] as! [String : AnyObject]**

[Image of error message within code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WSvO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because swift is not certain that your **array** in `if let array = allUsers["user_info"]` is an **array** . You can cast it like below and it should not complain:

```
if let array = allUsers["user_info"] as? [AnyObject] {
    //you code
}
```

**AnyObject** would be the type of your array's content.